# Jenkins update via comand line Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, updates

I want to update my Jenkins in a Ubuntu 20.04 lts and I would like to know how to do it by command line. I have been trying to look for good and simple documentation but have not found any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update the apt packages to fetch the latest versions
sudo apt-get update

To upgrade Jenkins:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install jenkins
```

And then restart the Jenkins server

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```